# Can we change the field Parameters (Environment Parameters) in Webots using the controller?

Tags: webots

I am a new user to Webots. I just wanted to know whether the parameters that we set in the environment be able to change through the controller.

As an example, When we add a Distance sensor, will it be able to change its range through the controller, while the simulation is running

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the supervisor API allows you to change the scene tree while the simulation is running. This includes adding and removing nodes and changing the values of the fields of the nodes. An example of a supervisor controller changing the translation field of a robot node in the scene is available [here](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/supervisor-programming). You can modify this example to change any field of any node.